# Ruby string interpolate variables but dont alter regex

Tags: ruby, regex, string, heredoc, string-interpolation

I need to return a string that contains a regex and interpolates instance variables. The string needs to look like this:

```
"SELECT field1, field2 CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(field3, r"^\".*\"$") THEN 'this' WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(field3, r"^\[.*]$") THEN 'that' WHEN field3 = '(not provided)' THEN NULL ELSE 'the_other' END AS better_field_3, field4 FROM `interpolated_table_name1` AS tbl LEFT JOIN `interpolated_table_name2` AS tbl2 ON blah = blah"
```

I used this code to generate it:

```
def string_query
  statement = 
    <<-HEREDOC
      SELECT
        field1,
        field2
        CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(field3, r"^\".*\"$") THEN 'this'
          WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(field3, r"^\[.*]$") THEN 'that' 
          WHEN field3 = '(not provided)' THEN NULL
          ELSE 'the_other' END AS better_field_3,
        field4
      FROM `#{@dynamic_table_name1}` AS tbl
      LEFT JOIN `#{@dynamic_table_name2}` AS tbl2
        ON blah = blah
    HEREDOC
  statement.squish!
end
```

The string is housed in double quotes, which is why the regex is escaped. When I run this SQL upon the database to perform the query, the regex has been altered, and the extra backslashes to escape are not removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heredocs act like double quoted strings as far as backslash-escapes are concerned so you have to manually escape your backslashes by doubling them:

```
statement = 
  <<-HEREDOC
    SELECT
      field1,
      field2
      CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(field3, r"^\\".*\\"$") THEN 'this'
        WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(field3, r"^\\[.*]$") THEN 'that' 
        WHEN field3 = '(not provided)' THEN NULL
        ELSE 'the_other' END AS better_field_3,
      field4
    FROM `#{@dynamic_table_name1}` AS tbl
    LEFT JOIN `#{@dynamic_table_name2}` AS tbl2
      ON blah = blah
  HEREDOC
```

You could do away with the `statement` variable and call `squish` (or `squish!`) directly on the heredoc as well:

```
def string_query
  <<-HEREDOC.squish
    SELECT
      field1,
      field2
      CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(field3, r"^\\".*\\"$") THEN 'this'
        WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(field3, r"^\\[.*]$") THEN 'that' 
        WHEN field3 = '(not provided)' THEN NULL
        ELSE 'the_other' END AS better_field_3,
      field4
    FROM `#{@dynamic_table_name1}` AS tbl
    LEFT JOIN `#{@dynamic_table_name2}` AS tbl2
      ON blah = blah
  HEREDOC
end
```

BTW, I'm assuming that `@dynamic_table_name1` and `@dynamic_table_name2` are known to be safe so that you don't have to worry about interpolating those into your string without escaping.

---

The double quotes in this:

```
r"^\".*\"$"
```

have nothing to do with how Ruby treats the `^\".*\"$`. Double quotes inside a heredoc are just meaningless characters, they're nothing special. The heredoc itself provides the "double quoted string" context that is causing your backslashes to be treated specially.